# Consistency on display of horizontal axis on 30 minutes interval in High stock graphs

Tags: javascript, highcharts, datetime-format

I want to display the horizontal axis on 30 minutes interval when 9h is selected. 
Code:

```
xAxis: {
          tickInterval: 30*60*1000,
                          minorTickInterval: 30*60*1000,

            events: {
              setExtremes: function(e) {
                if (typeof(e.rangeSelectorButton) !== 'undefined') {
                    switch(e.rangeSelectorButton.text){
                    case "9h":
                        this.update({
                          tickInterval: 30*60*1000,
                          minorTickInterval: 30*60*1000
                        }, false)
                        break;
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/3z5mss01/28/)

The issue is that interval is not consistent throughout. 
Sometime it is 30 minutes, sometimes it is 1 hour 15 minutes.

Series data which has been used here between 7th hour of the day to 19th hour excluding Saturday and Sunday. 
At least, it should be consistent for interval where data is available.

Refer to these images: 
[image]

[image]

Is there any way we could make it consistent.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Using ordinal=false, I got the consistency in the interval but it displays the points for weekends also for which there is no data. Fiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/hvme2pt0/2/

Comment: Could you mark on the image where exactly this inconsistency occurs? It seems to me that when 9h button is selected (bottom image) the tick interval always is 30 minutes (as expected).

Comment: @KamilKulig Horizontal axis interval is 1 hour 30 minutes in first image and 30 minutes in second image.

Comment: I see now. Another strange thing (seems like a bug to me - you can report it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues) is that Highcharts generates a lot of 'crowded' minor grid lines between the points that are starts end ends of no-data areas (e.g. between Mar 16, 14:21:40 and Mar 17, 1:3640 here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dy4rL9bx/).